# Data table no carga datos al ser seleccionado de una lista PHP

Tags: php, ajax, adminlte

Hola desde gracias por la atención y orientación, primero aclarar que estoy aprendiendo de este mundo de la programación el cual he ido de a poco comprendiendo por medio de un curso que estoy siguiendo; en mi avance estoy estancado para avanzar, he comparado el código pero no veo donde esta el problema para que se ejecute el procedimiento. Desde ya gracias por el tiempo!

Aquí se selecciona el producto:

[image: Aquí se selecciona el producto]

---

Selecciono el producto pero no se carga en table:

[image: Selecciono el producto pero no se carga en table]

---

El proyecto sugiere esto:

[image: El proyecto sugiere esto]

```
<div class="col-md-12">
    <table id="lstProductosVenta" class="display nowrap table-striped w-100 shadow ">
        <thead class="bg-info text-left fs-6">
            <tr>
                <th>Item</th>
                <th>Codigo</th>
                <th>Id Categoria</th>
                <th>Categoria</th>
                <th>Producto</th>
                <th>Cantidad</th>
                <th>Precio</th>
                <th>Total</th>
                <th class="text-center">Opciones</th>
                <th>Aplica Peso</th>
                <th>Precio Por Mayor</th>
                <th>Precio Oferta</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody class="small text-left fs-6">
        </tbody>
    </table>
```

---

```
var table;
var items = []; // SE USA PARA EL INPUT DE AUTOCOMPLETE
var itemProducto = 1;

$(document).ready(function(){

======================================================================================
INICIALIZAR LA TABLA DE VENTAS
======================================================================================*/        
table = $('#lstProductosVenta').DataTable({
    "columns": [
        { "data": "id" },
        { "data": "codigo_producto" },
        { "data": "id_categoria" },
        { "data": "nombre_categoria" },
        { "data": "descripcion_producto" },
        { "data": "cantidad" },
        { "data": "precio_venta_producto" },
        { "data": "total" },
        { "data": "acciones" },
        { "data": "aplica_peso" },
        { "data": "precio_mayor_producto" },
        { "data": "precio_oferta_producto" }
    ],
    columnDefs: [{
            targets: 0,
            visible: false
        },
        {
            targets: 3,
            visible: false
        },
        {
            targets: 2,
            visible: false
        },
        {
            targets: 6,
            orderable: false
        },
        {
            targets: 9,
            visible: false
        },
        {
            targets: 10,
            visible: false
        },
        {
            targets: 11,
            visible: false
        }
    ],
    "order": [
        [0, 'desc']
    ],
    "language": {
        "url": "//cdn.datatables.net/plug-ins/1.10.20/i18n/Spanish.json"
    }
});

/* ======================================================================================
TRAER LISTADO DE PRODUCTOS PARA INPUT DE AUTOCOMPLETADO
======================================================================================*/
$.ajax({
    async: false,
    url: "ajax/productos.ajax.php",
    method: "POST",
    data: {
        'accion': 6
    },
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function(respuesta) {

        for (let i = 0; i < respuesta.length; i++) {
            items.push(respuesta[i]['descripcion_producto'])
        }

        $("#iptCodigoVenta").autocomplete({

            source: items,
            select: function(event, ui) {

                CargarProductos(ui.item.value);                                                            
                
                $("#iptCodigoVenta").val("");

                $("#iptCodigoVenta").focus();

                return false;
            }
        })


    }
});

/* ======================================================================================
EVENTO QUE REGISTRA EL PRODUCTO EN EL LISTADO CUANDO SE INGRESA EL CODIGO DE BARRAS
======================================================================================*/
$("#iptCodigoVenta").change(function() {
    CargarProductos();        
});
```

Comment: Podrias agregar la repsuesta de la solicitud  a `ajax/productos.ajax.php`

Comment: Si claro, de hecho estoy volviendo a revisar a ver "si encuentro algo" y mirando los video. Muchas Gracias

Comment: `}else if(isset($_POST["accion"]) && $_POST["accion"] == 6){  // TRAER LISTADO DE PRODUCTOS PARA EL AUTOCOMPLETE

    $nombreProductos = new AjaxProductos();
    $nombreProductos -> ajaxListarNombreProductos();

}else if(isset($_POST["accion"]) && $_POST["accion"] == 7){ // OBTENER DATOS DE UN PRODUCTO POR SU CODIGO

    $listaProducto = new AjaxProductos();

    $listaProducto -> codigo_producto = $_POST["codigo_producto"];
    
    $listaProducto -> ajaxGetDatosProducto();`

Comment: Disculpa este es el inicio del ajax, gracias!`<?php

require_once "../controladores/productos.controlador.php";
require_once "../modelos/productos.modelo.php";

require_once "../vendor/autoload.php";

class ajaxProductos{

    public $fileProductos;

    public $codigo_producto;
    public $id_categoria_producto;
    public $descripcion_producto;
    public $precio_compra_producto;
    public $precio_venta_producto;
    public $utilidad;
    public $stock_producto;
    public $minimo_stock_producto;
    public $ventas_producto;

    public $cantidad_a_comprar;`